# How to set form data in Angular form through ts file

Tags: angular

I have one component AlertpopupComponent in which have one form like this

```
`alertForm=this.fb.group({
emailAlert:[null],
alertType:[null]
});`
```

I have another component dashboardComponent in which I have table, I want to set alertpopComponent form data for each row in table.
alertPopupContent=AlertpopupComponent;
My question is that how to set Data in alertPopupContent?

Comment: what is `alertPopupContent`?

Comment: alertPopupContent is  a variable

Comment: I think you should redesign your component. Think separately about `template` and `content`. Make sure you pass only "content" and paste the content into template that you already prepare.